# What's the word for something that has a mind of its own?

Tags: word-choice

An example could be the lawnmower that works sometimes, but seems to have a mind of its own.

It could also be the literal word for having a mind of its own, to describe any being.

Comment: Intelligent....?

Comment: A word for *thinking* things have a mind of their own is *animism*.

Comment: The idiomatic usage is usually 'having a mind of its own'. 'Sentient' is used literally.

Comment: They are just called bolshie.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when something - mechanical/electronic/non-human animal- is described as 'having a mind of its own', it's because it doesn't *agree* with the person describing it. In those cases, the thing is often called by the personality perceived. Ex:

"An *ornery* old truck."

"A *moody* computer."

"A *snobbish* goldfish."

When something (like, *my* car) exhibits a multi-faceted personality, I am forced to concede that she has a ***soul***.

Comment: +1 from me anyway. Both temperamental and ornery were what came to my mind

Answer (score 2):

> Besides [Human intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_intelligence), we have - 
>    **Artificial intelligence**: ([AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence))

Artificial general intelligence (AGI) is the intelligence of a (hypothetical) machine that could successfully perform any intellectual task that a human being can.

> The intelligence exhibited by machines, (lawnmower etc.) or software
>   (watsapp etc.)

([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence))

Answer (score 1):

I like the expression "self-aware"

> The computer which controlled the machines, Skynet, sent two Terminators back through time. .... It becomes self-aware at 2:14 a.m. Eastern time, August 29th.

Answer (score 1):

Nonsentient (mechanical/electrical) devices that don't always work as intended are often called...

> [**temperamental**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/temperamental) (informal) working erratically and inconsistently; unreliable
>    *a temperamental sewing machine*

There are even a few written references in Google Books to [*a temperamental lawnmower*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22temperamental%20lawnmower%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - but as you might expect, [*a temperamental computer*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22temperamental%20computer%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is far more common.

---

If you want to more explicitly "anthropomorphize" (assign human characteristics to) the device, you might say [*it's got a mind of its own.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%27s%20got%20a%20mind%20of%20its%20own%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: +1  from me anyway.  Both *temperamental* and *ornery* were what came to my mind.